# Why does GHC needs a functional dependency to infer the type of this expression

Tags: haskell

Consider the example of functional dependencies taken from [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies)

```
class Extract container elem | container -> elem where
  extract :: container -> elem

instance Extract (a,b) a where
  extract (x,_) = x
```

I understand why a functional dependency between `container`and `elem` is needed to avoid ambiguity with

```
instance Extract (a,b) b where
  extract (x,_) = x
```

However, if we do not have this latter instance, why can't the compiler figure the type of `extract ('x', 3)` instead of returning the following error?

```
<interactive>:408:1:
Could not deduce (Num t0)
from the context (Num t, Extract (Char, t) elem)
  bound by the inferred type for ‘it’:
             (Num t, Extract (Char, t) elem) => elem
  at <interactive>:408:1-20
The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
  it :: forall elem t. (Num t, Extract (Char, t) elem) => elem
Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
```

I tried to do `extract('x', 3 :: Int)` and in this case it generates the error:

```
<interactive>:409:1:
No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘print’
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Show a => Show (Control.Applicative.Const a b)
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Applicative’
  instance Show a => Show (Control.Applicative.ZipList a)
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Applicative’
  instance Show a => Show (Data.Complex.Complex a)
    -- Defined in ‘Data.Complex’
  ...plus 149 others
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

What are the limitations of GHC that requires a functional dependency in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Look into the'open world' assumption.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Can you be more specific / clear?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson The "open world assumption" tells that a typeclass can have any number of instances defined anywhere. Thus this means that the functional dependency is always necessary, even when there is only one instance, because no one knows if more instances will be added in the future, and so, to prevent future ambiguity GHC forces who defines the typeclass to provide a fundep "à priori" so that he or she will not have to change the typeclass later to accomodate the new instances, and doing so, avoid also the need to change the first instance?

Comment: @mljrg Why the accent in *a priori*? It's a latin locution, not a french one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it helpful to use `:t` when the typechecker runs into ambiguity.

```
:set -XMultiParamTypeClasses 
:set -XFunctionalDependencies 
:set -XFlexibleContexts 
:set -XFlexibleInstances 

class Extract big small where extract :: big -> small
instance Extract (a, b) a where extract = fst
```

So, with that out of the way:

```
:t let oneTwo = (1, 2) :: (Int, Int)
:t extract oneTwo
extract oneTwo :: Extract (Int, Int) small => small
```

Note! Even though the compiler knows that `Extract (Int, Int) small` is the only instance it doesn't *use* that information for type resolution. In order words:

```
:t {- in an alternate universe -} extract oneTwo
extract oneTwo :: Int
```

The reason is subtle: you actually wouldn't *want* that behavior. If that information were used, this compiler or the binary might do something come Friday that it wasn't doing on Monday. Because I could define

```
{- in an alternate universe -}
instance Extract (a, b) a where
  extract = fst
instance Extract (a, b) String where
  extract = const "hey girl"
```

Now `extract oneTwo` could do one of two things:

- Arbitrarily pick between `:: Int` or `:: String`. This violates the principle of least surprise. An instance defined at point A managed to act on code defined all the way over at point B.
- Error out! This *also* violates the principle of least surprise. An instance defined at point A made code all the way over at point B stop type-checking.

So, in the face of two evils, what we can do is just not use instances to resolve types.

### Promises, promises

Now, what if you *promised* that a second instance could never come along?

```
class Extract' big small | big -> small where
  extract' :: big -> small

instance Extract' (a, b) a where
  extract' = fst

:t extract' oneTwo
extract oneTwo :: Int
```

Now there are exactly one or zero instances of `Extract' big small` for every choice of `big`. It's now valid to use the instance for type resolution. For this, and more cartwheels, see [24 Days of GHC Extensions](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-14-functional-dependencies.html).